# USB Laser Pointer (remote control) doesn't work with LibreOffice Impress

Tags: usb, libreoffice, pointers

I use Ubuntu Studio 16.04 LTS, 64 bit version, into an Intel i5 PC.

I got an USB Laser Pointer intended to use, as a remote control, to LibreOffice Impress presentations.

BUT... It doesn't work.

The device is new (0 miles) and works (at least, all lights become to ON when I press its buttons)

What's wrong here?

Comment: Does the device require drivers? Maybe it isn't compatible with Linux.

Comment: Nothing is written into the instruction manual, and each time I press a button, the HDD light of my PC is ON, so... I guess Linux is recognizing the device itself. I guess.

Comment: Can you give us the make and model of the laser pointer? That will help us check out the mfg website and model user manual pdf. Remember your mileage may vary :)

Comment: Of course! ULTRA 29UPL00200 USB Laser Pointer & Presenter

Comment: Curiously, the device works so fine into my Laptop (also Ubuntu Studio 16.04 LTS 64 bit)!!! Why it doesn't work into my desktop? Maybe, a conflict with the USB keyboard and mouse devices? If this is the case, How can I fix it?

Comment: Sorry for delay I was writing my own complicated question. When I google your ULTRA all that came up was two websites in Spanish. Where did you buy this? Is there a link you can provide? Your laser pointer is basically a wireless mouse if that helps you wrap your brain around the problem visa ve the Laptop vs. Desktop. Go into `System Settings`, `Mouse & Touchpad` to see what's there.